# List.append/extend + operators and +=

Tags: python, list, append, extend

I'm having a really hard time trying to understand the behaviour of this code below. In python 3.6

The example code below is an abstraction of my actual code. I have done this to better describe my issue. I'm attempting to add a list to another list. Resulting in a two dimensional list. For the purpose of checking membership, of that list at a later time. Though I can't manage to add my list in the way i'd like Eg.

```
a_list = []
another_list = [7,2,1]

a_list.DONT_KNOW(another_list)
another_list = [7,3,1]
```

**results:**

```
a_list
[[7,2,1]]
another_list
[7,3,1]
```

**Example of my issue:**

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_list = []
        self.another_list = [0]
####### Modifying .extend/.append##############
        self.a_list.append(self.another_list) #  .append() | .extend(). | extend([])
###############################################
    def bar(self):
######## Modifying operator########
        self.another_list[0] += 1 #              += | +
###################################
        print('a_list = {} another_list = {} '.format(self.a_list, self.another_list))

def call_bar(f, repeats):
    x = repeats
    while x > 0:
        x -= 1
        foo.bar(f)

f = foo()
call_bar(f,3)
```

**Repeated 5 times. Modifying the list.function and the increment operator. Outputs**:

```
        # .append() and +=
a_list = [[1]] another_list = [1]
a_list = [[2]] another_list = [2]
a_list = [[3]] another_list = [3]

        # .extend() and +=
a_list = [0] another_list = [1]
a_list = [0] another_list = [2]
a_list = [0] another_list = [3]

        # .append() and +
a_list = [[1]] another_list = [1]
a_list = [[2]] another_list = [2]
a_list = [[3]] another_list = [3]

        #.extend() and +
a_list = [0] another_list = [1]
a_list = [0] another_list = [2]
a_list = [0] another_list = [3]

        #.extend([]) and +
a_list = [[1]] another_list = [1]
a_list = [[2]] another_list = [2]
a_list = [[3]] another_list = [3]
```

Notice that in all these examples when I get the two dimensional array (I need). The values in **a_list** change when manipulating **another_list**. How do I get the code to do this?

```
     #SOME METHOD I DON'T KNOW
a_list = [[0]] another_list = [1]
a_list = [[0]] another_list = [2]
a_list = [[0]] another_list = [3]
```

Comment: a_list.append(another_list[:])

Comment: That does indeed work. Using a slice must return a copy I take it?

Comment: Yes, it copies each entry in the list.  Some people consider it to be the idiomatic way to copy a list, some just consider it ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `self.a_list.append(self.another_list.copy())` to create a snapshot of `another_list` that is then added to `a_list`. Your code actually adds `another_list` as element of `a_list`, so it is natural that later edits would change the contents of that object.

Comment: Awesome! thanks mate. Makes sense, though not immediately obvious.\

Answer (score 0):

If you want `a_list` to stay as `[[0]]` regardless of what happens to the first value in `another)list`, why not just initialize it as `[[0]]` in `__init__`?

```
def __init__(self):
    self.a_list = [[0]]
    self.another_list = [0]
    # End of __init__; nothing else
```

With `append`, you add a reference of `another_list` as the first element of `a_list`. With `extend`, you add the references of the elements of `another_list` into `a_list`.

Comment: Not quite what i'm trying to achieve. Though the explanation of append and extend is appreciated :)

Comment: Np, but what are you trying to achieve? B/c my answer produces the same results as the one you marked as correct, but it avoids calling `copy()`.

Comment: "I'm attempting to add a list to another list. Resulting in a two dimensional list. For the purpose of checking membership, of that list at a later time."